# Parsing a element with name space not working xpath

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I no I will got shot down before I ask this but I tried implmenting a name space xml but its still not working for my xml document its from service center maanger.

```
public void  GetCriteraParamters(string QueryParmeterString, string xpath)
        {
            List<QueryCritera> listCriteraParameter = new List<QueryCritera>();

            XmlDocument currentDocument = new XmlDocument();
            currentDocument.LoadXml(QueryParmeterString);
            string path = xpath;
            XmlNodeList nodeList = currentDocument.SelectNodes(path);
            XmlElement elm = currentDocument.DocumentElement;
            XmlNodeList listCritera= elm.ChildNodes;

            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(currentDocument.NameTable);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("QueryCriteria", "http://Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Core.Criteria/");
            var topicNodes = currentDocument.SelectNodes("Expression", nsmgr);

            List<QueryCritera> qp = new List<QueryCritera>();
            string itemSource="";
            for (int i = 0; i < listCritera.Count; i++)
            {
                QueryCritera qpList = new QueryCritera();

                 string myString = listCritera[i].InnerXml.ToString();


                 string  xml2 = XElement.Parse(myString).ToString();

                 XmlDocument currentDocument2 = new XmlDocument();
                 currentDocument2.LoadXml(xml2);
                 XmlNodeList nodeList2 = currentDocument.SelectNodes(xpath);
                 foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList2)
                 {
                     itemSource = node.InnerXml;


                 }

            }


}
```

I need to be able to select the nodes under the cirtiera specifically the expression ones.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <View>
  <Data>
    <Adapters>
      <Adapter AdapterName="dataportal:EnterpriseManagementObjectProjectionAdapter">
        <AdapterAssembly>Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.SdkDataAccess</AdapterAssembly>
        <AdapterType>Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.SdkDataAccess.DataAdapters.EnterpriseManagementObjectProjectionAdapter</AdapterType>
      </Adapter>
      <Adapter AdapterName="viewframework://Adapters/AdvancedList">
        <AdapterAssembly>Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.ViewFramework</AdapterAssembly>
        <AdapterType>Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.ViewFramework.AdvancedListSupportAdapter</AdapterType>
      </Adapter>
      <Adapter AdapterName="omsdk://Adapters/Criteria">
        <AdapterAssembly>Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.SdkDataAccess</AdapterAssembly>
        <AdapterType>Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.SdkDataAccess.DataAdapters.SdkCriteriaAdapter</AdapterType>
      </Adapter>
    </Adapters>
    <ItemsSource>
      <AdvancedListSupportClass xmlns="clr-namespace:Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.ViewFramework;assembly=Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.ViewFramework" xmlns:av="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" DataTypeName="" AdapterName="viewframework://Adapters/AdvancedList" FullUpdateAdapter="dataportal:EnterpriseManagementObjectProjectionAdapter" DataSource="mom:ManagementGroup" IsRecurring="True" RecurrenceFrequency="{x:Static s:Int32.MaxValue}" FullUpdateFrequency="1" Streaming="true">
        <AdvancedListSupportClass.Parameters>
          <QueryParameter Parameter="TypeProjectionId" Value="$MPElement[Name='System.WorkItem.Incident.View.ProjectionType']$" />
        </AdvancedListSupportClass.Parameters>
      </AdvancedListSupportClass>
    </ItemsSource>
    <Criteria>
      <QueryCriteria xmlns="http://tempuri.org/Criteria.xsd" Adapter="omsdk://Adapters/Criteria">
          <Criteria>
          <FreeformCriteria>
            <Freeform>
              <Criteria xmlns="http://Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Core.Criteria/">
                <Expression>
                  <And>
                    <Expression>
                      <SimpleExpression>
                        <ValueExpressionLeft>
                          <Property>$Context/Property[Type='CoreIncident!System.WorkItem.Incident']/TierQueue$</Property>
                        </ValueExpressionLeft>
                        <Operator>Equal</Operator>
                        <ValueExpressionRight>
                          <Value>$MPElement[Name="IncidentTierQueuesEnum.Tier2"]$</Value>
                        </ValueExpressionRight>
                      </SimpleExpression>
                    </Expression>
                    <Expression>
                      <SimpleExpression>
                        <ValueExpressionLeft>
                          <Property>$Context/Property[Type='CoreIncident!System.WorkItem.Incident']/Status$</Property>
                        </ValueExpressionLeft>
                        <Operator>NotEqual</Operator>
                        <ValueExpressionRight>
                          <Value>$MPElement[Name="CoreIncident!IncidentStatusEnum.Resolved"]$</Value>
                        </ValueExpressionRight>
                      </SimpleExpression>
                    </Expression>
                    <Expression>
                      <SimpleExpression>
                        <ValueExpressionLeft>
                          <Property>$Context/Property[Type='CoreIncident!System.WorkItem.Incident']/Status$</Property>
                        </ValueExpressionLeft>
                        <Operator>NotEqual</Operator>
                        <ValueExpressionRight>
                          <Value>$MPElement[Name="CoreIncident!IncidentStatusEnum.Closed"]$</Value>
                        </ValueExpressionRight>
                      </SimpleExpression>
                    </Expression>
                    <Expression>
                      <UnaryExpression>
                        <ValueExpression>
                          <GenericProperty Path="$Context/Path[Relationship='WorkItem!System.WorkItemAssignedToUser' SeedRole='Source']$">Id</GenericProperty>
                        </ValueExpression>
                        <Operator>IsNull</Operator>
                      </UnaryExpression>
                    </Expression>
                  </And>
                </Expression>
              </Criteria>
            </Freeform>
          </FreeformCriteria>
        </Criteria>
      </QueryCriteria>
    </Criteria>
  </Data>
    <Presentation>
    <Columns>
      <mux:ColumnCollection xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:mux="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SystemCenter/Common/UI/Views/GridView" xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" xmlns:datebinding="clr-namespace:Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.Extensions;assembly=Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.UI.Extensions">
        <mux:Column Name="id" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id, Mode=OneWay}" Width="150" DisplayName="Header_Id" Property="Id$ReturnValueAsBigInt$" DataType="s:String" />
        <mux:Column Name="title" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Title, Mode=OneWay}" Width="200" DisplayName="Header_Title" Property="Title" DataType="s:String" />
        <mux:Column Name="sDisplayName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Status.DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}" Width="100" DisplayName="Header_Status" Property="Status.DisplayName" DataType="s:String" />
        <mux:Column Name="priority" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Priority, Mode=OneWay}" Width="100" DisplayName="Header_Priority" Property="Priority" DataType="s:Int32" />
        <mux:Column Name="targetTime" DisplayMemberBinding="{datebinding:DateBinding Path=TargetResolutionTime, Mode=OneWay}" Width="100" DisplayName="Header_Target_Resolution_Time" Property="TargetResolutionTime" DataType="s:DateTime" />
        <mux:Column Name="aDisplayName" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=AffectedUser.DisplayName, Mode=OneWay}" Width="150" DisplayName="Header_Affected_User" Property="AffectedUser.DisplayName" DataType="s:String" />
        <mux:Column Name="lastModified" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=$LastModified$, Mode=OneWay}" Width="150" DisplayName="Header_Last_Modified" Property="$LastModified$" DataType="s:DateTime" />
      </mux:ColumnCollection>
    </Columns>
    <ViewStrings>
      <ViewString ID="Header_Id">$MPElement[Name="System.WorkItem.Incident.Queue.Tier2.Unassigned.View.Header_Id"]$</ViewString>
      <ViewString ID="Header_Title">$MPElement[Name="System.WorkItem.Incident.Queue.Tier2.Unassigned.View.Header_Title"]$</ViewString>
      <ViewString ID="Header_Status">$MPElement[Name="System.WorkItem.Incident.Queue.Tier2.Unassigned.View.Header_Status"]$</ViewString>
      <ViewString ID="Header_Priority">$MPElement[Name="System.WorkItem.Incident.Queue.Tier2.Unassigned.View.Header_Priority"]$</ViewString>
      <ViewString ID="Header_Target_Resolution_Time">$MPElement[Name="System.WorkItem.Incident.Queue.Tier2.Unassigned.View.Header_Target_Resolution_Time"]$</ViewString>
      <ViewString ID="Header_Affected_User">$MPElement[Name="System.WorkItem.Incident.Queue.Tier2.Unassigned.View.Header_Affected_User"]$</ViewString>
      <ViewString ID="Header_Last_Modified">$MPElement[Name="System.WorkItem.Incident.Queue.Tier2.Unassigned.View.Header_Last_Modified"]$</ViewString>
    </ViewStrings>
  </Presentation>
  </View>
```

Its this values i hope to pull out into a stronlgy typed object that I have created?.

```
 <Expression>
              <And>
                <Expression>
                  <SimpleExpression>
                    <ValueExpressionLeft>
                      <Property>$Context/Property[Type='CoreIncident!System.WorkItem.Incident']/TierQueue$</Property>
                    </ValueExpressionLeft>
                    <Operator>Equal</Operator>
                    <ValueExpressionRight>
                      <Value>$MPElement[Name="IncidentTierQueuesEnum.Tier2"]$</Value>
                    </ValueExpressionRight>
                  </SimpleExpression>
                </Expression>
                <Expression>
                  <SimpleExpression>
                    <ValueExpressionLeft>
                      <Property>$Context/Property[Type='CoreIncident!System.WorkItem.Incident']/Status$</Property>
                    </ValueExpressionLeft>
                    <Operator>NotEqual</Operator>
                    <ValueExpressionRight>
                      <Value>$MPElement[Name="CoreIncident!IncidentStatusEnum.Resolved"]$</Value>
                    </ValueExpressionRight>
                  </SimpleExpression>
                </Expression>
                <Expression>
                  <SimpleExpression>
                    <ValueExpressionLeft>
                      <Property>$Context/Property[Type='CoreIncident!System.WorkItem.Incident']/Status$</Property>
                    </ValueExpressionLeft>
                    <Operator>NotEqual</Operator>
                    <ValueExpressionRight>
                      <Value>$MPElement[Name="CoreIncident!IncidentStatusEnum.Closed"]$</Value>
                    </ValueExpressionRight>
                  </SimpleExpression>
                </Expression>
                <Expression>
                  <UnaryExpression>
                    <ValueExpression>
                      <GenericProperty Path="$Context/Path[Relationship='WorkItem!System.WorkItemAssignedToUser' SeedRole='Source']$">Id</GenericProperty>
                    </ValueExpression>
                    <Operator>IsNull</Operator>
                  </UnaryExpression>
                </Expression>
              </And>
            </Expression>
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you are trying to do? Do you just need an xpath expression to select the Criteria element? What is the problem you are having?

Comment: @MikeHixson No I need the all the elements contained with it the expression elements so I do.

Comment: @MikeHixson Any ideas on the xpath to get the expression values cause no matter what i try in c# dont appear to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using XmlDocument with xml that has namespaces in it, you need to use XmlNamespaceManager to create aliases for those namespaces. In your XPath statements you use the aliases in front of the element names. Give this a try:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

// Give the namespace an alias that we will use in our XPath statement
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("a", "http://Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Core.Criteria/");

// Find any Criteria node tagged with the "a" namespace
XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//a:Criteria", mgr);

Console.WriteLine(node.OuterXml);
```